# Python Passing Object to Object

Tags: python

Good Day,

So I have an object called PointArray and another object called Graph. I am passing the object point to Graph as such

```
class Graph:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pointArray = PointArray()
    description = "This is a class"
    author      = "Raaj"

    def setPointArray(self,pointArray):
        self.pointArray=pointArray

    def plotFFTGraph(self):
        xArr=[]
        yArr=[]
        for point in self.pointArray.freqArray
            xArr.append(point.X)
            yArr.append(point.Y)

        subplot(2,1,2)
        plot(xArr,yArr)
```

The problem is, Python doesn't seem to recognize that I can access freqArray!

I get this

```
for point in self.pointArray.freqArray
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have imported everything correctly. What gives this error?

Comment: Read what the error message is saying. If it couldn't recognize that you could access freqArray, it would give you something like an `AttributeError: 'Spam' object has no attribute 'freqArray'`. But it's saying `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`—that means there's something wrong with your punctuation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the colon:

```
for point in self.pointArray.freqArray:
    #                  ---------------^
```

Comment: I am new to the language. apologize for that

Answer (score 0):

Change it to `for point in self.pointArray.freqArray:`